# How to add Child CMS page to Parent CMS page?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages

I'm Having two pages

1. parent_page
2. child_page

and I'm having a child page link inside a parent page.
If i click on child page link the url should be

**www.xyz.com/parent_page/child_page**
when the url look like this i can't display the child page content

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to connect the Pages like category Parent >> child URL structure.

You need to manully set the `URL Key` as per requirement like below:

```
parent.html

parent/child.html
```

Comment: thank you for answers......can u pls tell me How to pass custom attribute values instead of child.phtml ?

Comment: You can pass but then you need to validate custom value `CMS Router - app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Controller/Router.php`

Comment: No sir...i can't access default code in magento...is there any other way to get output?...or any sample process in internet?

Comment: No You need to override CMS Router to apply your logic instead of directly modify core file. Also you can work on `cms_controller_router_match_before` event.

Comment: Sry sir i'm new in magento....Can you pls share sample process ?

Comment: Please check Router class from line no 89 to last, how magento verify the CMs Page URL key

Comment: i can't understand what is really happening in router.....Is there any extensions for this?

Comment: Hello sir got result with another method thank you